# Mongo: If any array position matches single query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assuming this data structure:

```
{
    "title": "Foo bar",
    "username": "jackwreid"
},
{
    "title": "Bish bosh",
    "username": "lizziebump"
},
{
    "title": "Ham nam",
    "username": "lizziebump"
},
{
    "title": "Blub blub",
    "username": "jvarn"
}
```

And assuming

```
var userFollowing = ["lizziebump", "jackwreid"]
```

How would I do a `db.posts.find()` for posts where the username matches any of the contents of the `userFollowing` array?

I'm trying to build a query that returns posts by users in the current user's following list and I can only find docs on how to do this the other way around where the query returns posts if a single query string is in any array position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

```
db.collection.find({username: {$in: userFollowing}})
```

Comment: I knew this was a simple one, I just couldn't spot this in the docs. Thank you! I'll approve in 5 mins.