# Mongo query that matches field to any element of array

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I am trying to query a Mongo Db through R (rmongodb package). i have a simple requirement:

- Return records where the field "email" matches any of the emails in the vector usr$email. I think I am close but just not able to find the right syntax to pull it through.

I saw this response to an earlier question ([Mongo: If any array position matches single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644850/mongo-if-any-array-position-matches-single-query)) and am trying along the lines:

```
eids_l <- paste0("'", unique(usr$email), "'", collapse=", ")
eids_l1 <- sprintf("[ %s ]", eids_l)
q <- sprintf('{"email": {"$in": %s}}', eids_l1)
cursor <- mongo.find.all(mongo, namespace, buf)
```

I still get an error:

```
Error in mongo.bson.from.JSON(arg) : 
  Not a valid JSON content: {"email": {"$in": [ 'xx@gmail.com',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cursor <- mongo.find.all(mongo, "namespace", query='{ "email": {
>   "$in":   ["xx@gmail.com", "yy@gmail.com", "zz@gmail.com" ] } }')

Be careful with the use of apostrophes(') and quotation marks(").

I always use the rmongodb Cheat sheet:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/vignettes/rmongodb_cheat_sheet.pdf